# My Auth Component No Longer Lets Me Log Out

Tags: cakephp, cookies, authentication

Another day, another Auth component headache.  Everything was working fine for me until a couple of hours ago; at which point, I can no longer log my Auth-logged-in user out.  I click on the link to go to users/logout, or I type users/logout in directly; the application seems to think about it for a while, before redirecting to the index page, with my logged in use still logged in.

It seems as though the logout function of the users controller isn't even being touched, as I can't seem to get a die statement to work in there.  Can anyone think of a reason why I would be being bounced away from my logout function?  Or some sensible steps I can take to discover the truth about what is going on here?  As usual I just cannot think of anything I could have done to turn a working application into a broken one...

ETA: Asking Safari to remove all cookies seems to clear the problem (though of course it reemerges).  Are cookies likely to be an issue in this sort of thing?  If so, what can I do to ensure that cookies don't prevent the possibility of logging out of my application?

Comment: Well, it is better than not letting you log in! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please post the code for your `logout` method, you also said 'the login function isn't even being touched', it shouldn't be if you're trying to log the user out

Comment: Well spotted!  I actually think I may have worked out what's going on, on my way home - I think somehow the group of the logged in user *doesn't have access permissions to the logout action*.  If that turns out not to be the case, I'll certainly post my code.  Otherwise I'll just feel a bit silly :)

Comment: Yeah, my users just weren't being allowed access to the logout action.  The Auth component does enough things automagically that I assumed it would give global permission to logout, but apparently not.  I've added in the line $this->Auth->allowedActions = array('login', 'logout'); in the UsersController beforeFilter and it seems to work now.  Thanks for offering to help though!